# Magento2: How do I add a filter for "is_in_stock" on category page layered navigation?

Tags: magento2.4

I need to be able to filter products by availability on the category page in the catalog. Is it possible to filter the standard Magento is_in_stock attribute?

Comment: I tried the option above and it only works correctly for one page. If I have 24 products on my page, I can see a total of 24 products (in stock and out of stock) through these filters. If I filter by them, I see, for example, 23 products on the page and an opportunity to go to the next page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try below solution:**

**1. Create `di.xml` file to the following path:**

app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <plugin name="stock-filter-category-navigation" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Plugin\FilterList" sortOrder="100" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**2. Create a `Stock.php` file to the following path:**

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Layer\Filter\Stock.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Layer\Filter;

class Stock extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter
{
    const IN_STOCK_COLLECTION_FLAG = 'stock_filter_applied';
    
    protected $_activeFilter = false;
    protected $_requestVar = 'in-stock';
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory $filterItemFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder $itemDataBuilder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($filterItemFactory, $storeManager, $layer, $itemDataBuilder, $data);
    }

    public function apply(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $filter = $request->getParam($this->getRequestVar(), null);
        if (is_null($filter)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $this->_activeFilter = true;
        $filter = (int)(bool)$filter;
        $collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        $collection->setFlag(self::IN_STOCK_COLLECTION_FLAG, true);
        $collection->getSelect()->where('stock_status_index.stock_status = ?', $filter);
        $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter(
            $this->_createItem($this->getLabel($filter), $filter)
        );
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return __("Stock");
    }

    protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        if ($this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getFlag(self::IN_STOCK_COLLECTION_FLAG)) {
            return [];
        }

        $data = [];
        foreach ($this->getStatuses() as $status) {
            $data[] = [
                'label' => $this->getLabel($status),
                'value' => $status,
                'count' => $this->getProductsCount($status)
            ];
        }

        return $data;
    }
    
    public function getStatuses()
    {
        return [
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock::STOCK_IN_STOCK,
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK
        ];
    }
   
    public function getLabels()
    {
        return [
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock::STOCK_IN_STOCK => __('In Stock'),
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK => __('Out of stock'),
        ];
    }
    
    public function getLabel($value)
    {
        $labels = $this->getLabels();
        if (isset($labels[$value])) {
            return $labels[$value];
        }
        return '';
    }

    public function getProductsCount($value)
    {
        $collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        $select = clone $collection->getSelect();
        // reset columns, order and limitation conditions
        $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
        $select->where('stock_status_index.stock_status = ?', $value);
        $select->columns(
            [
                'count' => new \Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT(e.entity_id)")
            ]
        );
        return $collection->getConnection()->fetchOne($select);
    }
}
```

**3. Create the `FilterList.php` file to the following path:**

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Plugin\FilterList.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Plugin;

class FilterList
{
    const STOCK_FILTER_CLASS  = 'Vendor\Extension\Model\Layer\Filter\Stock';
   
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_layer;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_stockResource;
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status $stockResource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_stockResource = $stockResource;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        $outOfStockEnabled = $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Configuration::XML_PATH_DISPLAY_PRODUCT_STOCK_STATUS,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        return $outOfStockEnabled;
    }

    public function beforeGetFilters(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList\Interceptor $filterList,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer
    ) {
        $this->_layer = $layer;
        if ($this->isEnabled()) {
            $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();
            $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore($collection->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
            $this->_addStockStatusToSelect($collection->getSelect(), $websiteId);
        }
        return array($layer);
    }

    public function afterGetFilters(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList\Interceptor $filterList,
        array $filters
    ) {
        if ($this->isEnabled()) {
            $filters[] = $this->getStockFilter();
        }
        return $filters;
    }

    public function getStockFilter()
    {
        $filter = $this->_objectManager->create(
            $this->getStockFilterClass(),
            ['layer' => $this->_layer]
        );
        return $filter;
    }

    public function getStockFilterClass()
    {
        return self::STOCK_FILTER_CLASS;
    }

    protected function _addStockStatusToSelect(\Zend_Db_Select $select, $websiteId)
    {
        $from = $select->getPart(\Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
        if (!isset($from['stock_status_index'])) {
            $joinCondition = $this->_stockResource->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                'e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id' . ' AND stock_status_index.website_id = ?',
                $websiteId
            );

            $joinCondition .= $this->_stockResource->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                ' AND stock_status_index.stock_id = ?',
                \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**4. Execute below commands:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution immediately filters the selection of products, this is not exactly what I need. I need to be able to have a switch in the filter on the category page that will allow me to choose whether to display products in stock or out of stock

Comment: Oh Okay. Understood. You want to place a filter to the category page layered navigation. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need

Comment: Okay. Got it. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try this solution now.
Just FYI: Your question title & description is different.

Comment: I'm already trying the solution. Yes, I apologize for the question that was originally incorrectly posed

Comment: If it works then please accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is working fine!