# Magento2: How to add a filter for "is_in_stock" on category page layered navigation?

Tags: magento2, filter

I tried the solution from **[Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371972/magento2-how-do-i-add-a-filter-for-is-in-stock-on-category-page-layered-navig/372249#372249)**, but it only works correctly for one page. If I have 24 products on my page, I can see a total of 24 products (both in stock and out of stock) through these filters. When I apply the filters, I see, for example, 23 products on the page and have the option to go to the next page. What am I doing wrong?"